# Dividing sentences into sub-sentences using re package in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a data of many sentences, regarding one example as the following sentence, I want to split it into 2 sub sentences:

> Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma
>   from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B)
>   |T:**1SP3E3| ; |I:**1SP3E3| |L:**1SP3E3| in contrast, 3/3 plasma shows
>   virtually no lipid staining at the beta-position. |T:**1SN3E3|
>   |I:**1SN3E3| |L:**1SN3E3|

split it to:

> Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma
>   from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B)

and

> in contrast, 3/3 plasma shows virtually no lipid staining at the
>   beta-position.

My code is:

```
newData =[]
for item in Data:
    test2= re.split(r" (?:\|.*?\| ?)+", item[0])
    test2 =test2[:-1]
    for tx in test2:
        newData.append(tx)
print len(newData)
print newData
```

However, I got 3 items in the result, including a `;`. I checked the original sentence and found that, the `;` is in `|T:**1SP3E3| ; |I:**1SP3E3|`, so I need to remove this `;` out from the result. I modified my code into

```
test2= re.split(r" (?:\|.*?\| ?;?)+", item[0])
```

But I can not get the correct result. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you simply split the string on the pipe character, and grab every 6-th element of the resulting list? Of do you expect pipe character in the actual text as well?

Comment: `re.split(r" (?:\|.*?\|[\s;]*)+", s)` may get you a bit closer. It will give you an empty third string, since the second series of "code blocks" doesn't really split anything.

Comment: If it gives an empty third string you can just use the `filter` function. `result=re.split(r" (?:\|.*?\|[\s;]*)+", s)` after this use filter `result = filter(None,result)`

Comment: @Evert, you solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[i.strip() for i in re.sub(r'\|\w:\*\*\w*\|', '', re.sub(r' +', r' ', s.strip())).split(';')]
```

Returns

```
['Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B)', 'in contrast, 3/3 plasma shows virtually no lipid staining at the beta-position.']
```

But take with a grain of salt since it depends on if your text is consistent with your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x="""Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B) |T:**1SP3E3| ; |I:**1SP3E3| |L:**1SP3E3| in contrast, 3/3 plasma shows virtually no lipid staining at the beta-position. |T:**1SN3E3| |I:**1SN3E3| |L:**1SN3E3|"""
print [i for i in re.split(r"(?:\|[^:]*:.*?\|(?:[\s;]+|$))+",x) if i]
```

Output will look like this:

> ['Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B) ', 'in contrast, 3/3 plasma shows virtually no lipid staining at the beta-position. ']

Answer (score 0):

import re

string = [str.strip() for str in re.sub('\|\w:**\w+\|', '', string).split(';')]

Output will be:
['Both whole plasma and the d < 1.006 g/ml density fraction of plasma from 2/2 mice show this broad beta-migration pattern (Fig. 1 B)', 'incontrast, 3/3 plasma shows virtually no lipid staining at the beta-position.']

Answer (score -1):

This pattern match part b: `(?: ?\|.*?\|\ ?\;?)`
You can use your code to split both part.
Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/dO9rH1/1) in regex101